# WebApi impossible to send proper encoded file to front (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, encoding, arrays, asp.net-web-api2

I am receiving a Base64 encoded string that contains a word document (generated by thunderHead), that I decode with:

```
byte[] dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data)
```

When I write directly this byteArray into a file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("myFile.doc", dataByte);
```

The word document is properly written (é, è are shown properly), but it's not the case when I send this byteArray to the front (angularjs):

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(dataByte);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");(also tried "application/octet-stream")
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachement");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Filename = "toto.doc"
return response;
```

I can't figure it out....some help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: How do you open the file on the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, as @peco pointed, the problem was on the front part, I was doin a $http.post(url, data).then ... and missed to add {responseType: 'arrayBuffer'} as a third parameter: $http.post(url, data, {responseType: 'arrayBuffer'}).then... Thanks.